# How to remap backspace when using ibus and vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard, gvim

First I do

```
:inoremap <BS> x
```

and then enter insert mode. Then switch to Hangul input in ibus. Now I try to type

```
마
```

and it shows up as

```
ㅁx마
```

I guess that makes sense, right? ibus must have generated a backspace to get rid of the `ㅁ` and replace it with `마`. But it means that I can't remap backspace without interfering.

Is there something I can do to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about ibus, but you could try [this plugin](https://github.com/hsanson/vim-im), referenced on [a similar question on vim_use](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/8BdZlnIX1u4).

---

Maybe you could use `inoremap <BS> <c-r>=Backspace()<CR>` and create a `Backspace()` function to somehow detect the situation where the map expansion should be avoided, similar to [Vim Tip 68 - "Checking for bad mappings"](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Backspace_and_delete_problems). Maybe you could check for the sequence inserted by ibus using `feedkeys()`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this is an issue that occurs during insert mode with hangul mode on (which I need it to be) so I don't think this will solve my problem.

Comment: I see -- I've added another suggestion.